# Which exception can be generated when subtracting ESP or RSP register? (stack growing)

Tags: linux, assembly, linux-kernel, x86-64

I'm trying to understand how exactly memory pages for stack is allocated/assigned.

I wrote the following proof-of-concept C-code which obviously causes segmentation fault (on x86_64 Linux):

```
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char a;

    memset( (&a - 4444444), 0, 3333333 );

    return 0;
}
```

The following fragment of assembly code (AT&T syntax) is generated by gcc from above C-program:

```
subq    $16, %rsp
leaq    -1(%rbp), %rax
subq    $4444444, %rax
movl    $3333333, %edx
movl    $0, %esi
movq    %rax, %rdi
call    memset
```

If I add `subq $5555555, %rsp` manually before calling `memset`:

```
subq    $16, %rsp
leaq    -1(%rbp), %rax
subq    $4444444, %rax
movl    $3333333, %edx
movl    $0, %esi
movq    %rax, %rdi
subq    $5555555, %rsp /* added manually */
call    memset
```

Then segmentation fault disappears because virtual memory pages for stack was assigned after  subtracting `rsp` register caused some hardware exception and assigned exception handler was called (of course, in kernel space).

I know that calling `memset` here will cause "minor page fault" exceptions. But it's a different story (i.e. allocating physical memory pages).

My question is: Which exception was generated when `subq $5555555, %rsp` is invoked? I suggest it would be "stack fault" exception but I did not find exact proof for it.

Comment: x86 doesn't even have these registers... perhaps you used the wrong architecture tag?

Comment: @Ben Voigt I have `Intel® Core™ i3-2328M CPU @ 2.20GHz × 4`, so it's x86 registers.

Comment: RSP is not an x86 register... it's available on your CPU only in long mode, which is not x86.

Comment: @BenVoigt: He is talking about "x86_64" which means x86 in 64-bit mode also known as "amd64" or "x64" architecture. The stack pointer is RSP in this architecture.

Comment: @uintptr_t: Are you sure a general protection fault is generated? If Linux reports "general protection fault" it does not necessarily mean that the CPU reported that fault. It is possible that the CPU actually reports "page fault" and the Linux kernel will report "general protection fault" as consequence to this page fault.

Comment: @MartinRosenau: Yes, and there is a tag [tag:x86_64] for that.

Comment: I've changed tag, thanks.

Comment: @MartinRosenau: I updated my topic. Please, check my answer to my own question.

Comment: @uintptr_t Feel free to actually write it as an answer (that's allowed and welcome).

Comment: @glglgl Thank you. I moved "update" section to answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out. First of all, subtracting `rsp` register does nothing. Second, when we try to write to non-mapped stack area "minor page fault" exception handler is invoked in kernel space. Then this page fault handler checks whether it was legal write or non-legal. I think page fault handler compares with current stack pointer of the thread (in our case it's saved value `rsp` register). If address where process try to write is upper than current stack pointer then page fault handler expand process's virtual address space and maps this virtual page to physical page, otherwise handler sends SIGSEGV to the process.

I examined the following fragment by using GDB and /proc/[pid]/maps:

```
subq    $1500016, %rsp
movq    %fs:40, %rax
movq    %rax, -8(%rbp)
xorl    %eax, %eax
movb    $44, -1500016(%rbp)
movb    $55, -1100016(%rbp)
movb    $66, -600016(%rbp)
```

When `subq    $1500016, %rsp` is invoked stack address range isn't changed.
But when first write happens by `movb    $44, -1500016(%rbp)`, stack address range is expanded as I explained above.

Answer (score 0):

There is no exception on that line.

However, `memset`'s prologue code will cause an access violation when it tries to preserve registers by saving them to the stack, as the stack pointer is invalid.

In most environments, there is only a single guard page that triggers additional stack pages to be committed.  In that case the access violation will not be handled by growing the stack, the program will simply crash.

In case your OS actually does handle the access violation caused during register save, it will commit all the intervening pages of stack and retry the operation (the `PUSH` instruction).  Then those intervening pages will be successfully written by the loop inside `memset`.

Of course, if the subtraction causes `RSP` to point outside the address space reserved for stack growth, all bets are off.  You could even cause the stack of some other thread to grow.

Comment: I updated my topic. Please, check my answer to my own question.

Comment: Your explanation doesn't match the actual behaviour. With the `subq $555555, rsp` line, all goes well. if your answer was correct, that wouldn't work...

Comment: @Ben: Linux only does stack expansion for the main (initial) thread.  Secondary threads need to have their full stack mapping actually allocated up front, because letting it grow isn't safe.  The "magic" that stops other allocations (with `mmap(MAP_ANONYMOUS)`) from stealing pages the stack is expected to grow into only works for the main thread.   But yes if you were using an unsafe `MAP_GROWSDOWN` for your thread stacks, then you could extend them.

Comment: @glglgl:  The paragraph about guard pages is how Windows works.  The paragraph after describes Linux, where you can expand anywhere within `ulimit -s` without stack probes.  It's not described very explicitly, but it looks correct.